# React native determine if user is at the top of the screen

Tags: javascript, react-native, scrollview, scrolltop

In javascript in web I would do something like this to determine if user is at the top of the scrollable page/document:

```
$(document).scroll(function() { 
   if($(window).scrollTop() === 0) {
     //do stuff
   }
});
```

Is there something similar in React Native that could help me to determine if user is at the top of the screen or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a `ScrollView` you can do something like this:

```js
_handleScroll(event) {
    if(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y <= 0) {
        console.log('top!');
    }
}
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <ScrollView 
                onScroll={this._handleScroll}     
                onScrollAnimationEnd={this._handleScroll} 
                style={{flex: 1}}>
                    <View style={[styles.child, {backgroundColor: 'red'}]} />
                    <View style={[styles.child, {backgroundColor: 'orange'}]} />
                    <View style={[styles.child, {backgroundColor: 'green'}]} />
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
    );
}
```

```js
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    },
    child: {
        flex: 1,
        height: 400,
    }
});
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Yes
**ScrollView** component has **onScroll** method. pageX and pageY properties

`evt
  nativeEvent
    contentOffset 
      x
      y`

```
handleScroll(event) {
 console.log(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y)
},

<ScrollView onScroll={this.handleScroll}/>
```

Comment: contentOffset.y is the correct one, pageY is relative to screen size not whole page. :)